# How to apply a function to a selected element, coverting Jquery code to JS and getting type error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change a Jquery function to vanilla JS and I have issues replicating it. I have fixed some errors it threw, but now I am entirely stuck.

The Jquery code

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    var windowHeight, windowScrollPosTop, windowScrollPosBottom = 0;

    function calcScrollValues() {
        windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        windowScrollPosTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;
    }

    jQuery.fn.revealOnScroll = function (direction, speed) {
        return this.each(function () {

            var objectOffset = jQuery(this).offset();
            var objectOffsetTop = objectOffset.top;

            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("hidden")) {

                // if argument is "right"
                if (direction == "right") {
                    jQuery(this).css({
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "right": "700px",
                        "position": "relative"
                    });
                    // if argument is "left"
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).css({
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "right": "-700px",
                        "position": "relative"
                    });

                }
                jQuery(this).addClass("hidden");
            }
            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("animation-complete")) {

                // if the page has been scrolled far enough to reveal the element
                if (windowScrollPosBottom > objectOffsetTop) {
                    jQuery(this).animate({"opacity": 1, "right": 0}, speed).addClass("animation-complete");
                } // end if the page has scrolled enough check
            } // end only reveal the element once
        });
    }
    function revealCommands() {
        jQuery(".title").revealOnScroll("right", 1200);
    }

    calcScrollValues();
    revealCommands();

    // run the following on every scroll event
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        calcScrollValues()
        revealCommands();
    }); // end on scroll

});
```

This work, if you uncomment the Jquery code in the pen.

Here is the JS code

```
function calcScrollValues() {
    windowHeight = screen.height;
    windowScrollPosTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;
};
window.onload = function () {
    var windowHeight, windowScrollPosTop, windowScrollPosBottom = 0;

    function revealOnScroll(direction, speed) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var objectOffset = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            var objectOffsetTop = getBoundingClientRect();

            if (!this.classList.contains("hidden")) {
                // if argument is "right"
                if (direction == "right") {
                    this.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0; right:700px; position: relative');
                }
                ;
                // if argument is "left"
            } else {
                this.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0; right:700px; position: relative');
            }
            ;
            this.classList.add("hidden");
        });
        if (!this.classList.contains("animation-complete")) {

            // if the page  scrolled far enough to reveal the element
            if (windowScrollPosBottom > objectOffsetTop) {
                this.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:1; right:0; transition: speed + "ms"');
                this.classList.add("animation-complete");

            } // end if the page has scrolled enough check

        }
        ; // end only reveal the element once
    }
}

function revealCommands() {
    document.querySelector(".title").revealOnScroll("right", 1200);
}
calcScrollValues();
revealCommands();

// run the following on every scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    calcScrollValues()
    revealCommands();
});
```

I know that the 'return this.each(function() {}' part cannot possibly work in JS, and have no idea how to get the JS code for that.

And the other main issue is this
    'document.querySelector  (".title").revealOnScroll("right", 1200);'
obviously gives a Type error"not a function".

There are probably even more issues with this, but this is the one which has me stuck.

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/yYKyaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code added the `revealOnScroll` method to the object returned by jQuery when querying for `.title` (via `jQuery.fn.revealOnScroll`). By querying with the browser, you lost the `jQuery` object but got a `NodeList` from `document.querySelectorAll('.title')` instead (you shouldn't use `document.querySelector` as it returns only one element - this is not what you had before with jQuery). You now need to add the `revealOnScroll` method to the prototype of the `NodeList` in order to use it like you did before with jQuery.

After doing so, you hit some other problems: `NodeList` looks like, but is no `Array` and has no iterator by itself, but you can lend the one from `Array.prototype.forEach`.

You also lose the `this` binding, but using the `element` provided by `forEach` instead should just work fine.

I haven't checked the code completely. It gets interpreted without errors but I had to make some changes to it, like moving function calls inside the `onload` function.

Please check it line by line and report back if you encounter problems that you can't solve on your own.

```js
function calcScrollValues() {
    windowHeight = screen.height;
    windowScrollPosTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;
};
window.onload = function () {
    var windowHeight, windowScrollPosTop, windowScrollPosBottom = 0;

    NodeList.prototype.revealOnScroll = function(direction, speed) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(self, function (element, index) {
            var objectOffset = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            var objectOffsetTop = getBoundingClientRect();

            if (!element.classList.indexOf("hidden") !== -1) {
                // if argument is "right"
                if (direction == "right") {
                    element.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0; right:700px; position: relative');
                };
            // if argument is "left"
            } else {
                element.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0; right:700px; position: relative');
            };
            element.classList.add("hidden");
          
            if (element.classList.indexOf("animation-complete") === -1) {
                // if the page  scrolled far enough to reveal the element
                if (windowScrollPosBottom > objectOffsetTop) {
                    element.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:1; right:0; transition: speed + "ms"');
                    element.classList.add("animation-complete");
                } // end if the page has scrolled enough check
            }; // end only reveal the element once
        });
    }
    
    calcScrollValues();
    revealCommands();
}

function revealCommands() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".title").revealOnScroll("right", 1200);
}

// run the following on every scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    calcScrollValues()
    revealCommands();
});
```

```html
<div class="title" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It runs, but with one flaw, If you try the codepen now(I am using the p.test element to test, the rest is separate code) you will see that the elements passed in the revealOnScroll come into the screen vertically instead of from the side. This is actually the next thing I'd have done anyway, but now I am wondering why this is happening. Looks like the issue is here:
"var objectOffset = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            var objectOffsetTop = getBoundingClientRect();"

Comment: I wanted to ask some details about the code you have provided. So, we add the revealOnScroll method to the nodeList prototype and pass the direction and animation speed as arguments to that. We use nodeList as that is what's returned from querySelectorAll. So far i get it. Then,
the Array.prototype is extended to use forEach and use call() on that. Now I don't understand the first argument to call(),the "self". What is "self"?

Comment: @damianocelent copy and paste mistake. Just replace it with `this`.